# replace string with varying content using powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a set of folders in which there are some json files. I am  trying to write a powershell script to convert the below line for all the json in the folder:

```
"objectStatus": "ACTIVE",
```

The above line from json files can differ with more than one space between the key and value:

```
"objectStatus":     "ACTIVE",
```

The script that I wrote is:

```
$jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.json -rec
foreach ($file in $jsonFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"ACTIVE"','"INACTIVE"'} |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

You can see that the above replaces the string '"ACTIVE"' to '"INACTIVE"'. However, I want to replace the '"ACTIVE"' string only when the key is "objectStatus". Also, there can be more than one space between the key and value. How can I handle that while replacing the string?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `-replace '\s+"ACTIVE"'` to get the white spaces.

Comment: Use `ConvertFrom-Json` to deserialize the JSON file into objects, modify the objects and serialize back to JSON using `ConvertTo-Json`. This way you don't need to worry about the formatting of the JSON file, as `ConvertFrom-Json` sorts it all out. For more detailed help, please include a bigger sample of your JSON file, that shows the parent objects of `objectStatus`.

Comment: Thanks @zett42, your solution works! I am going with your approach as it modifies the exact key-value pair that I want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make search by full string like this. `'"objectStatus":\s*"ACTIVE"','"objectStatus": "INACTIVE"'`

```
$jsonFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.json -rec
foreach ($file in $jsonFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"objectStatus":\s*"ACTIVE"','"objectStatus": "INACTIVE"'} |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```